# Каким образом создать статическую версию динамической страницы для ее индексации в поисковике?

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, seo, search

Никак не пойму как индексировать ajax страницы. Ну вроде немножечко понял. И понял только то, что чтобы страница была в поисковике нужно добавить копию страницы с названием моего `url + _escaped_fragment_` в виде обычного html (чтобы поисковик смог распознать текст). Также вроде как понял, что эти копии можно делать автоматом. В частности вроде есть решение - [prerender](https://gist.github.com/thoop/8072354). Ни с apache, ни с Node.js, ни с Ruby раньше дел не имел.

Можете мне объяснить, что я должен сделать чтоб мой ajax сайт индексировался? Вставить это в `htacces` на сервере? Или что? И вообще я всё правильно понял?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: А чего непонятного? Вроде всё развёрнуто написал. Хочу видеть свой сайт в поисковике. Сделан он по технологии ajax. Как?

Comment: Спасибо за правку

Comment: Подскажите, как ваш вопрос относится к программированию, и что конкретно вы хотите видеть в ответе? Пример настройки сервере? Способ создания статической версии страницы? Что-то другое?

Comment: Не знал куда податся. решил обратится сюда. Может помогут. Я ожидал что мне расскажут что нужно делать. Уже гуглил - ничего не понял. А если в случае с prerender ожидал что мне в принципе могут дать пошаговую инструкцию, т.к., как я уже писал, опыта у меня в этом вообще нет. не знаю что делать